# Print n largest values from BST

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to print `n` largest values from BST, I have certainly problem with pointers, here is my part of code.

```
    void bt_printN(node *leaf,int *n)
{
    if((leaf != NULL) && *n > 0)
    {
        bt_printN(leaf->right,n);
        printf("%s %d\n",leaf->word, leaf->i);
        *n--;
        bt_printN(leaf->left,n);
    }
}
```

And this does not work, what is proper way to pass `n` value to such recursive function ?

Comment: The passing is OK; it is the decrementing that isn't.  `*n--` decrements the pointer, not the pointed at value; you need `(*n)--` to decrement the value.  Whether everything else is OK is a separate discussion; it looks like it is more likely to print the N smallest values — except, as has been pointed out, you're doing RHS first, so...you may well be OK after all.

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes, I see it will work with the largest values first.  I suspect that the code should be checking `*n > 0` after the recursion on`leaf->right` before printing out the current node, because the value of `n` may have shrunk via the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is not the way you're passing `n`; the primary problem is that `*n--` decrements the pointer, not the pointed at value.  You need `(*n)--` to decrement the value pointed at.

With that fixed, your code is most of the way there — despite my red herring comments about 'smallest first'.  However, I think you need to check `n` after the recursive call `bt_printN(leaf->right, n);` and before the function prints its own node.  You don't have to check before the second recursive call, though it might be a minor (minimal) optimization to do so.  As written, if `*n == 1` on entry, it recurses rightwards, but then each node on the way down the RHS prints its value, even though only one was required.